# JHipster microservices as a single project

Tags: java, gradle, microservices, jhipster

Working with JHipster.

I can not find examples, so the question.

Is it possible to create JHipster based on microservices as a single project?

Most examples are like https://github.com/viniciusboson/jhipster-microservice-example, i.e. each microservice is a separate project.

I would like to see:

```
.git
microservice1
microservice2
gateway
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The link you mentioned does it in exact the way you want to see. The microservice architecture can be expanded to

```
.git
orderbook
commission
production
billbook
deliverybook
...
gateway
```

Of course every microservice is a complete application of its own and will run without the others.

Take a look at [Sasidharans Book](https://www.packtpub.com/eu/application-development/full-stack-development-jhipster), [The new Voxxed websites](http://youtube.com/watch?v=SRyDJC1Ff0M) and [Raibles Book](http://infoq.com/minibooks/jhipster-mini-book-5) - here you'll find examples of how to build microservice architectures with generator-jhipster.

Comment: But what if I want to get gradle multi-module project here, and not in manual way, but from "JHipster box", using generator-jhipster, for example?
my-app
+ .git
+ build.gradle
+ 1st gradle sub-project (microservice1)
+ 2nd gradle sub-project (microservice2)
+ ...
+ Nth gradle sub-project (gateway)